# How do I get the menu to slide up from bottom button instead of just appearing? HTML/CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, animation

I have tried many different ways to do it but the menu appears the exact same way each time. Things I´ve tried: height 0->20%, width 0->100%, jQuery, JavaScript, slideUp/Down, hide/Show, margin-bottom: -50%->0%, animate etc.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#settings-menu-btn").click(function(){
    $("#nav").slideDown(500);
  }); 

  //Hiding the menu
  $("#close-menu-btn").click(function(){
      $("#nav").slideUp("slow");
  }); 
});
```

```css
.nav{
  display: none;
}

.menu {
  padding: 0 10% 10%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, $accent-color, $dark-primary-color);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, $accent-color, $dark-primary-color);
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;  
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: $max-width-menu;
  max-height: $max-height-menu;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav" id="nav">
   <ul class="menu" id="menu">
      <li>menu item</li>
   </ul>
</div>

<div class="settings-menu-link">
  <img id="settings-menu-btn" src="settings-icon.png">
</div>
```

Comment: If you run the snippet you can see you have an error in your javascript, please correct it

Comment: $("#nav).slideUp - small typo in there

Comment: @Sfili_81 do you mean the "runtime.lastError:"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved your issue, but let me just help you like this first.

You should almost never put your `script` tag before your HTML code, but always at the very bottom, before the `body` tag closes.

There are very few situations where you will have to load your script before the page has been fully loaded first. So try to avoid that.

Also, there is no reason to use a `translate` property on an element that has been positioned absolute/fixed. You can already move it with `top, right, bottom, left`.

Simply just give your navigation a negative value for `top` property, and then make a new class that will have `top` property equal to 0.

Then, on the click of your button, just toggle that class to navigation each time the button is clicked ! :)

Here is my solution to this, it will fix your issue :

https://codepen.io/Juka99/pen/WNGjNPG

Comment: Thank you for such a good explanation! I moved the script-tag, did not remove the translate + left-tags since I need the menu to stay centered (and margin + display won´t do that). Now I have a new class that slides the menu perfectly up from the bottom (I used bottom instead of top). My issue was also that the show menu-button was not the same as close menu-button but I used add/removeClass in two functions instead of  toggle. My problem for several days and the feeling is amazing! Thanks again!

Comment: Amazing ! :) 
Let me know if you need anything else !

Answer (score 1):

removed position and translate styling for menu and its working.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#settings-menu-btn").click(function(){
    $("#nav").slideDown(500);
  }); 

  //Hiding the menu
  $("#close-menu-btn").click(function(){
      $("#nav").slideUp("slow");
  }); 
});
```

```css
.nav{
  display: none;
}

.menu {
  padding: 0 10% 10%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, $accent-color, $dark-primary-color);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, $accent-color, $dark-primary-color);
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;  
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: $max-width-menu;
  max-height: $max-height-menu;
 /* position: fixed;*/
  bottom: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  left: 50%;
  background: #ff8a009e;
/*  transform: translateX(-50%);*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="settings-menu-link">
  <img id="settings-menu-btn" src="https://img.icons8.com/ios/452/settings.png" style="width:20px;">
</div>

<div class="nav" id="nav">
   <ul class="menu" id="menu">
      <li>menu item</li>
   </ul>
   <button id="close-menu-btn">close</button>
</div>
```

Comment: It solved the "just appearing" issue but it pushes the whole page down and puts the menu on top  of the page. My menu is bottom: 0 and that´s where I want it to slide up. And removing the translate does put the menu to the left instad of centered. Thank you for putting your time into this!